# How do I write this method to allow me to pass locator, string as parameters without error?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, frameworks

When I write the below method parameters as `string, string` it works. When I write it as `By, string`, it throws an error. I would like to understand why.

```
internal class Banner : BaseElement
{
    public Banner(string locator, string name) : base(locator, name)
    {
    }
}

internal class Banner : BaseElement
{
    public Banner(By locator, string name) : base(locator, name)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand you right, but do the BaseElement class have the two constructors (By, string) and (string, string)?

Comment: That's the thing, no, here's the class itself  

protected BaseElement(By locator, string name)
        {
            Name = name;
            this.locator = locator;
            wait = new Wait();
        }

Comment: Can you clarify your question title? I don't understand what you mean by "Why does the code work for the man I do not..."

Comment: The error message you get when using locator, string is likely going to be the answer to what's going wrong. Edit your question and add the full error message as text, properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to initialize a new Banner object one of two ways:

With a locator:

```
new Banner(By.Id("foo"), "...");
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or with a string instead of a `By` object:

```
new Banner("...", "...");
//         ^^^^^
```

Since Banner inherits from BaseElement, and the BaseElement constructor requires a `By` object, you can add a new constructor to Banner:

```
public class Banner : BaseElement
{
    public Banner(By locator, string name) : base(locator, name)
    {
    }

    public Banner(string htmlTagId, string name) : base(By.Id(htmlTagId), name)
    {//                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

This technique works as long as you want the first string to be interpreted as the same kind of locator in Selenium. For example, if you want to always pass the Id of an HTML tag when initializing a new Banner, then use `By.Id(...)` when passing the locator up to the parent class.

The downside with this approach is that you can only choose one kind of locator when passing a string as the first argument. If you want a different locator strategy, then use the constructor for Banner than accepts a `By` argument instead.